# Add aliases to built in discord.py function (help) without removing it

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to add aliases to the built-in command `help` in discord.py. However, I do *not* want to remove/rewrite it.

Right now, I'm doing something like this

```py
    @commands.command(aliases=['commandlist', 'commands'])
    async def _help(self, ctx):
        await self.bot.help(ctx)
```

But this isn't right (getting errors since 'Bot' object has no attribute 'help')

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Context.send_help`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.send_help):

```
@commands.command(aliases=['commandlist', 'commands'])
async def _help(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send_help()
```